# Sigma-algebras of a set that contains an empty set

Tags: measure-theory

I started learning about sigma-algebras today and I'm confused about the definition.
In the book that I am currently reading it states that the smallest sigma-algebra over a set S is {∅, S}. However, if S = {∅, {1}}, then {∅, S} = {∅, {∅, {1}}} does not seem to be a sigma-algebra over S because it is not closed under taking complements as
S\∅ = {{1}} ∉ {∅, S}.

If you could help me understand where am I wrong, I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of $\varnothing$ is $S\setminus\varnothing=S\in\{\varnothing,S\}.$

You confused it with $S\setminus\{\varnothing\}=\{\{1\}\}\notin\{\varnothing,S\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The definition is correct.
In your example  $S\backslash\emptyset = S$.

But $S\backslash\{\emptyset\} = \{\{1\}\}$

Comment: Same answer as mine

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah, but posted only two minutes later, so you can really blame SuperDedo for that ...

Comment: I don't blame him (I did not downvote), I just beg him to delete his duplicate.